# How to create a sentence from a dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, input

I am trying to make some code where the user inputs a sentence, the sentence is turned into a dict and then the dict is used to get the original sentence back.

Code:

```
import json
def code():
    sentence = input("Please write a sentence: ") 
    dictionary = {v: k for k,v in enumerate(sentence.split(), start=1)}   
    with open('Dict.txt', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(dictionary, fp)
    print(dictionary) 
    puncList = ["{","}",",",":","'","[","]","1","2","3","4","5"]
    for i in puncList:
        for sentence in dictionary:
            dictionary=[sentence.replace(i," ") for sentence in dictionary]
    print(' '.join(dictionary))
code()
```

Input:

```
Hello my name is Bob
```

Actual output:

```
{'Hello' : '1', 'name' : '3', 'Bob' : '5', 'my' : '2', 'is' : '4'}
Hello name Bob my is
```

Desired output:

```
{'Hello' : '1', 'name' : '3', 'Bob' : '5', 'my' : '2', 'is' : '4'}
Hello my name is Bob
```

This would be fine too:

```
{'Hello' : '1', 'my' : '2', 'name' : '3', 'is' : '4', 'Bob' : '5'}
Hello my name is Bob
```

For the part where I recreate the original sentence, it cant just print the sentence, it has to be from the dict.

Comment: You can use an OrderedDict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either use `OrderedDict` to retain the element order, or sort the dictionary elements before you print them out. You've already got an `OrderedDict` answer, so here's how to use the dict you created:

```
print(' '.join(k for (k, v) in sort(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])))
```

Incidentally, your approach has a bug: If you apply it to a sentence with repeated words, e.g., "boys will be boys", you'll find that there's no element with index `1` in your dictionary since `(boys, 4)` will overwrite `(boys, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `OrderedDict` on `enumerate`, like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

s = "Hello my name is Bob"

d = OrderedDict((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(s.split(), 1))
print(d)
# OrderedDict([('Hello', 1), ('my', 2), ('name', 3), ('is', 4), ('Bob', 5)])

s_rebuild = ' '.join(d)
print(s_rebuild)
# 'Hello my name is Bob'
```

Since the dictionary is already ordered, the values are not used for rebuilding the string.

Answer (score 1):

You logic is flawed in that it can't handle sentences with repeated words:

```
Hello Bob my name is Bob too
{'name': 4, 'Hello': 1, 'Bob': 6, 'is': 5, 'too': 7, 'my': 3}
name Hello Bob is too my
```

We can deal with that using a *defaultdict*, making the values arrays of word positions instead of individual numbers.  We can further improve things by dealing with your *punch list* up front via a *split*.  Finally, we can reconstruct the original sentence using a pair of nested loops.  We don't want/need an OrderedDict, or sorting, to do this:

```
import re
import json
from collections import defaultdict

PUNCH_LIST = r"[ {},:'[\]1-5]+"

def code():
    dictionary = defaultdict(list)

    sentence = input("Please write a sentence: ") 

    for position, word in enumerate(re.split(PUNCH_LIST, sentence), start=1):
        dictionary[word].append(position)

    with open('Dict.txt', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(dictionary, fp)

    print(dictionary) 

    position = 1
    sentence = []

    while position:
        for word, positions in dictionary.items():
            if position in positions:
                sentence.append(word)
                position += 1
                break
        else:
            position = 0

    print(' '.join(sentence))

code()
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
Please write a sentence: Hello Bob, my name is Bob too
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'is': [5], 'too': [7], 'Bob': [2, 6], 'Hello': [1], 'name': [4], 'my': [3]})
Hello Bob my name is Bob too
```

Where Dict.txt contains:

```
{"is": [5], "too": [7], "Bob": [2, 6], "Hello": [1], "name": [4], "my": [3]}
```

Note that the defaultdict is a convenience, not a requirement.  A plain dictionary will do, but you'll have to initialize the lists for each key.